# What is a difference between Android3 and Android4?

Tags: android

What is a difference between Android 3 and Android 4?

I was not able to google it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a high level list of [platform highlights](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-4.0-highlights.html) for each version on the Android SDK documentation page.

You can also see a list of API differences, which details changes to classes and methods. [This one is for changes introduced in API level 14](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/14/changes.html).

Answer (score 4):

http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-4.0-highlights.html